# Print order attachment in magento order mass action

Tags: magento-1.7, order-grid, massaction, attachment

I have an extension of order attachment installed in my magento 1.7. What I need to do is to have an option in mass action of order grid to print order attachment.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your **config.xml**

```
<events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <yourmodulename_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                    <class>yourmodulename/observer</class>
                    <method>addMassAction</method>
                </yourmodulename_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
```

your observer function

```
 public function addMassAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

            if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {


        $block->addItem('myname', array(
            'label' => 'myname',
            'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('module/index/order'),
            'target'    => '_blank'
        ));
    }



        }
```

Comment: What will be the controller name and code? Can you provide full code.

Comment: where you find the difficulty mention it.. i will try to help you

Comment: i change my code check it